# Magento 2 is it possible to get Magento Version via REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to use different functionality depending on the Magento version. Is it possible to get version via REST API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By default Magento there is no API endpoints to get the version.

Based on your needs, you can create new API class then inject `ProductMetadataInterface` or inject `ProductMetadataInterface` in existing class wherever needs.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata
) { 
    $this->productMetadata = $productMetadata; 
}

/**
 * Get Product version
 *
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getMagentoVersion() { 
    return $this->productMetadata->getVersion(); 
}
```

I hope you got solution to achieve your goal.

Comment: Are you confirming there is no default API endpoint for this purpose?

Comment: @DmitriPortenko as my knowledge, by default there is no endpoints.

Comment: @DmitriPortenko Yeah, In Magento there is no default API endpoint for to get the version. And also you can easily check the version like this way www.website.com/magento_version.

Comment: @DmitriPortenko Please note that we also have an option to disable this for some security reasons.
bin/magento module:disable Magento_Version
The following modules have been disabled:
- Magento_Version

Comment: thanks for the note, but I think any module can be disabled this way :)

Answer (score 2):

Summary of the proposed solutions.
1) From @sathish answer - I've created my own REST API. You can check the following [commit](https://github.com/troublediehard/mma-customapi/commit/aafce11a53b10bb506f0fa3a5b0f476452654bc3) or simply use [extension](https://github.com/troublediehard/mma-customapi).

2) From @renga comment, it is possible to get Magento version from `www.website.com/magento_version`. So I used the following code to get the Magento version in my React Native app.

```
const getMagentoVersion = async () => {
  try {
    const url = 'http://magento.base.url/';
    const response = await fetch(`${url}magento_version`);
    const text = await response.text();
    const number = parseNumber(text);
    console.log(text, number);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const parseNumber = (strg) => {
  strg = strg || '';
  let decimal = '.';
  strg = strg.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
  if (strg.indexOf(',') > strg.indexOf('.')) decimal = ',';
  if ((strg.match(new RegExp(`\\${decimal}`, 'g')) || []).length > 1) decimal = '';
  if (decimal != '' && (strg.length - strg.indexOf(decimal) - 1 == 3) && strg.indexOf(`0${decimal}`) !== 0) decimal = '';
  strg = strg.replace(new RegExp(`[^0-9$${decimal}]`, 'g'), '');
  strg = strg.replace(',', '.');
  return parseFloat(strg);
};

getMagentoVersion();
```